# Android textview with clickable phone number

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, tel

I have a textview showing
Phone: 0900-1111, Fax: 0900-2222

Is there a way to make the phone clickable but not the fax.

Using

`Phone: <a href="tel:09001111">0900-1111</a>, Fax: 0900-2222`

With autolink set to phone, both are clickable !

Comment: Why was this even closed and downvoted so much? It's a good question with a good answer.

Comment: 1853 views in 1 year. not a bad question I think

Comment: I find this a great question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you checked the API demos ?

They have a sample just for this , under Views/Text/Linkify.

The class is located at com.example.android.apis.text.Link.java

for example , the string used there for one of the textView is :

```
<string name="link_text_manual"><b>text2: Explicit links using &lt;a&gt; markup.</b>
  This has markup for a <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a> specified
  via an &lt;a&gt; tag.  Use a \"tel:\" URL
  to <a href="tel:4155551212">dial a phone number</a>.
</string>
```

and the textView is :

```
  <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/link_text_manual"
            />
```

Comment: I use that but I have 2 links instead of only the one specified vie the anchor tag...

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please show what you want to have , and what you've tried to do ? The sample there has plenty of different links , all are customizable and can be turned on/off.

Comment: Phone: 0900-1111, Fax: 0900-2222 ... I want the fax number NOT clickable. I tried with or without href=tel, but they are always BOTH clickable.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the autolink , as i've written ? Have you tried the sample ? Please try , and then update your question , as it doesn't contain a code sample that shows that it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks... Indeed I had to remove the autoLink to have the href working as defined in the string.

Comment: I had to enable `autolink` on the textview for the links to do something when clicking on them.