# How to create dial link on TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android and:

I have a TextView that can show a phone number.

I want to have that part of the text to be 'touchable' and attempt to make a phone call or something similar.

I have tried to implement [implicit intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for when the user clicks the TextView but I can't make it work.

Is there any solution to this? Or a different approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `android:autoLink="phone"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use built-in linkify. Read this tutorial, easy to understand: http://android.okhelp.cz/linkify-text-link-url-in-textview-text-android-example/

Answer (score 1):

First make your TextView `clickable` by adding below in your layout.xml

```
<TextView 
...
...
android:clickable="true">
</TextView>
```

And in your java code inside OnClickListener of that particular TextView Start phone activty as

```
TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_contact);

 tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel://"+ tv.getText().toString().trim())));

        }
    });'
```

And if you want link on specific text on textview then this  post may help you

[Android textview with clickable phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762956/android-textview-with-clickable-phone-number)

**Edit**

As @Apoorv suggested,you may also use `android:autoLink = "phone"` as

In the xml file, add the below lines.

```
<TextView
      ....
      android:autoLink = "phone"
/>
```

For more info see [android:autoLink - Have a Clickable Phone Number link in a TextView, in XML](http://androidsbs.blogspot.in/2013/10/have-clickable-phone-number-link-in.html)